# Labels are missing in the Tree

Tags: diagrams, forest, trees

In the following tree, the labels are concatenated to their parent node. For example in the first branch of the tree from left, I would like to have "the" as a leaf, but it sticks to D (its parent). This is the LaTeX code I use:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{forest}
\forestset{.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,inner sep=2pt}}}

\begin{forest}
[TP
    [DP [D\\the] [NP [N\\man ]]]
    [T'
        [T\\will ]
        [VP
            [V\\eat ]
                [DP [D\\a ] [NP [N\\burger ]]]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
```

> Note: The code is taken from https://msu.edu/~amunn/latex/sharelatex-trees-forest-v1.pdf

This is the result of the code:

[image]

But I would like the results would be like this:

[image]

How can I fix this to have a tree like this:?

Comment: Please could you make your examples compilable? It makes it much easier and less pitfall-strewn to help.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[TP
    [DP [D,label=above left:the] [NP [N,label=above left:man
    ]]]
    [T'
        [T,label=above left:will ]
        [VP
            [V,label=above left:eat ]
                [DP [D,label=above left:a ] [NP [N,label=above left:burger ]]]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks for updating your question. You only need to make what you put in `.style` known to your tree.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={parent anchor=south, child
anchor=north,align=center,inner sep=2pt}
[TP
    [DP [D\\the] [NP [N\\man ]]]
    [T'
        [T\\will ]
        [VP
            [V\\eat ]
                [DP [D\\a ] [NP [N\\burger ]]]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I do not know where you got `.style...` from, I am not saying it is wrong but I have not seen it before. If you want every tree to have some universal `for tree`, consider using

```
\forestset{default preamble={
for tree={...}
}
}
```

as discussed on p. 7 of the manual.

Comment: Yeah, exactly, something like this but a bit cleaner and tidier (I updated my question with example)

Comment: @woody I made an update. Is that closer to what you want?

Comment: It is wrong marmot and `default preamble` should be used. See page 99 of the Forest manual. @woody